# mssql throwing Failed to connect to DB, after connecting Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, database

### Background

I am making a very simple app that has a connection to a DB. I connect successfully and I am able to make queries, but every X I get an error.

### Code

My small app consists of the following code:

```
var mssql = require("mssql")

mssql.connect({
    "user": "someUSer",
    "password": "userPass",
    "database": "someDb",
    "server": "someServer",
    "options": { "encrypt": true }, 
    "pool": { 
        "max": 100000,
        "min": 1,
        "idleTimeoutMillis": 50,
        "evictionRunIntervalMillis": 5,
        "softIdleTimeoutMillis": 5
    } 
})
.then( () => {
    return mssql.query`SELECT TOP 2 Number FROM Devices`;
})
.then( console.log )
.catch( console.error );
```

This code works. It successfully prints the top 2 device numbers of the given table.

However there is an issue.

### Problem

Every X seconds I get the following error printed out:

> Error: Failed to connect to DB_ADDRESS in
>   15000ms
>       at Connection.tedious.once.err (/home/service/apps/teltonika-parser/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:216:17)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Connection.connectTimeout (/home/service/apps/teltonika-parser/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:795:12)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)

The weird thing is that all my connections seem to work, i.e., I can make queries and the DB will answer them normally.

### Research

At first I though it was an issue with password, users or something among those lines. Though that wouldn't make sense to me ( because I could query the DB ), I double checked and everything was fine.

Then I though that it was a problem with Promises in my app. After building this MWE, I concluded that **could not** be the case.

### Problem

What could possibly be causing this recurring error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Azure was having issues with their DB services. TO add to that, our DB was at 100% basically.

This explains the long delays and the connections failed, though it would have been nicer to have a little bit more information about why it was failing.